# Yii2 search field in update action

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to update query when user field search field and click on button "search", but  this is not send my get parameters to update action ..

here is view:

```
<?php
Pjax::begin([
            'enablePushState' => true,  // I would like the browser to change link
            'timeout' => 100000 // Timeout needed
        ]); 

echo LinkPager::widget([
              'pagination' => $pagination,
              'hideOnSinglePage' => true,
              'prevPageLabel' => 'Предишна',
              'nextPageLabel' => 'Следваща',
              'firstPageLabel' => 'Начало',
              'lastPageLabel' => 'Край'

           ]); ?>
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'action' => ['update'],
    'method' => 'get',
]); ?>

<input type="text" id="fname" class="form-control search-option-input" placeholder="търси прецификация по име, номер" name="search-query-main"  value=' '>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Search'), ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    <?= Html::resetButton(Yii::t('app', 'Reset'), ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) ?>
</div>
```

i use pjax for pager with result of all specification, because they are over 600 ... this code is in view _form and i want to send it with this search word to controller action Update, who can not work without $_GET['id']

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass ID in URL you can add it into `action` URL of your form:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'action' => ['update', 'id' => $id],
    'method' => 'get',
]); ?>
```

Comment: i want to pass and variable that user is searching

Comment: You have and input for user query. It does not work?

Comment: no ... it works only with post method, but not with get